# Maven Build Failure when calling mvn without lifecycle phase or goal

Tags: maven

Am try to build my project using Maven on Eclipse. The first build was awesome. After that I get this error :

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.129s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 28 17:51:35 GST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle
phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>
:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate,
initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources,
compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources,
generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test,
prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test,
verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean,
post-clean. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the
following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maven is a build tool, but unlike `ant` there is not "default" goal.  So when you run

```
 mvn
```

You are not supplying enough arguments, you need to run something like

```
 mvn test
```

Where the second argument indicates where along the [build lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) you wish to stop.  Maven will then run every step up to the one you specified.

Some common stopping points

```
 mvn compile (just compile)
 mvn test (compile and run unit tests)
 mvn package (compile, run unit tests, and build the distributable package)
 mvn install (all of the above, and install distributable package into local repository.
     Install is very useful if you need to build other packages which depend on changes
     to this package)
 mvn deploy (all of the above, and install package into remote (aka public) repository
     for sharing with other developers)
```

Comment: There is a [`<defaultGoal>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element) in Maven but it's not set by default.

Comment: @GeroldBroser Yes, there is a default goal, and the reason it isn't used heavily is because there's no one step on the build lifecycle that everyone agrees is the one that is needed right now.  So, defaultGoal tends to be the one that the build system desires (when you have a build system that's so bad, for legacy reasons , it can't provide a parameter).

Answer (score 7):

You can set a goal through command or eclipse :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify a build goal, e.g. *compile* or *install*. Check your eclipse launch configuration.