# How to "run configuration" for a Web application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, run-configuration

I am having trouble to run configuration for a web application in Eclipse. The Web application is in a Maven project and the Server is JBoss. For a normal Java application, there is a main class and from there I can run configuration. For a Web application, in Eclipse I usually just right click the project root, "run as -> run on server". It will start the server and launch the application.

If I click "run as configurations", Run configurations window gets opened. Then how to proceed from here to launch the Web application?

[image]

Comment: In all probability this project hasn't been set as a WAR project. Maybe if you enable faceted project support?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos How to set up it as a WAR project?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run a project, a "Run Configuration" is created automatically by the Eclipse. You should be able to see your Java project's Run Config when you expand **"Java Application"** menu in the Run config dialog. The same way your maven based project should also have a Run Config in the **"Maven Build"** menu, if you have run it at least once.

So Open "Run Configurations" dialog box. Expand **"Maven Build"** menu. Select your project's configuration & click on **"Run"** button. This will launch your application.

Comment: I received this "[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or ...". Do I need to specify a goal and how  in Maven Build?

Comment: Have you ever run that application from eclipse in any way?

Comment: Yes, many times. Not through "run as configurations", but through "run on server". That's normally how I run the application.

Comment: See these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606794/maven-build-failure-when-calling-mvn-without-lifecycle-phase-or-goal & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852950/specifying-goal-in-pom-xml

Comment: "The POM for com.bword.core:nlp:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available". My pom.xml is under the root directory of the project. Why can't it find it when running as configuration?

Comment: Go through this tutorial: [http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html]