# maven Build process failing in isolated VM

Tags: java, maven, build

I am facing one issue. I need to build a maven java spring application inside one VM. That VM is completely isolated and have no internet connectivity. Now to support build process , i places the repository folder from external sources(where this java application was building and executing perfectly) containing all required dependencies by this application , inside .m2 folder. So it looks like below

```
My VM
|- .m2
     |- reposirory , settings.xml
```

But problem is on giving command build process is failing, as its trying to download existing dependencies. Where exactly i am missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I configure Maven for offline development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233328/how-do-i-configure-maven-for-offline-development)

Comment: Could you place here your mvn command? Only to know if you using the param -o

Comment: just giving command mvn clean install

Comment: @KCS try run `mvn -o clean install`

Answer (score 0):

Working in offline mode

Try to Run the following command: mvn –o clean package

Comment: Unknown lifecycle phase "–o". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test,

Comment: @KCS Did you ran `mvn -o`? This message occurs when ran only this command

Comment: As @Rajkumar told you, run `mvn –o clean package`

Comment: its giving same error

Comment: Refer link -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606794/maven-build-failure-when-calling-mvn-without-lifecycle-phase-or-goal/33290497